# Proper way to call asynchronous function in swift singleton

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I want to build an analytics class for my application, and i am using singleton.

If I run this, the tagEvent function immediately runs rather than first running the openSession(), so sessionId returns nil.
How can I create a class like this with proper initialisation and use it application wide like singleton instances.

**Analytics.swift**

```
final class Analytics {
    public static let instance = Analytics()
    private var baseUrl = "http://localhost"
    public var deviceId: String?

    private init(){
       self.deviceId = SomeFunctionGetsDeviceID()
   }

   func openSession(){
       // make an API call to create a session and save sessionId to UserDefaults
       if let url = URL(string: self.baseUrl + "/session"){
           let params:[String:Any] = ["deviceId": "\(self.deviceId!)"]

           var request = URLRequest(url: url)
           request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

           AnalyticsSessionManager.sharedManager.request(request as URLRequestConvertible).validate().responseObject(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<SessionOpenResponse>) in
               if response.result.value != nil {
                   UserDefaults.standard.set(response.result.value?.sessionId, forKey: "sessionId")
               }
           })
       }
   }

   func closeSession(){
      // make an API call to close a session and delete sessionId from UserDefaults
     ...
   }

   func tagEvent(eventName: String, attributes: [String : String]? = nil) {
        if let url = URL(string: self.baseUrl + "/event"),
            let sessionId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sessionId"){
            ...
            // make an API call to create an event with that sessionId
        }
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Analytics.instance.openSession()
    Analytics.instance.tagEvent(eventName: "App Launch", attributes: 
    ["userID":"1234"])
}
```

Comment: `openSession` is definitely called before `tagEvent`. Most likely the issue is that `openSession` returns immediately because it makes an async call.

Comment: What does "make an API call" actually look like?

Comment: I edited the make an API call part @rmaddy

Comment: FYI - your issue has nothing to with this class being a singleton. It's a misunderstanding of how async calls work.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is the openSession function is doing work asynchronously and the tagEvent call comes in BEFORE the asynchronous code has completed.  There are a couple of ways around this:

1) Add synchronization so the tagEvent code will wait for the openSession call to complete (if in progress).  If not in progress, perhaps it should automatically call openSession, wait for completion, then execute the code in that function

2) Add a completion handler from openSession and inside that enclosure you can call tagEvent such as:

```
func openSession(completionHandler: @escapaing (Bool) -> ()){
    // make an API call to create a session and save sessionId to UserDefaults
    ...
    UserDefaults.standard.set(someSessionID, forKey: "sessionId")

    // when done with async work
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

Then in your app delegate:

```
Analytics.instance.openSession() { (success)
    Analytics.instance.tagEvent(eventName: "App Launch", attributes:["userID":"1234"])
}
```

3) *** This is the way I would fix it *** I would not make a call to openSession to be required outside of the class.  I would add a flag to the Analytics class:

```
private var initialized = false
```

In the openSession function, set this after everything is done

```
initialized = true
```

In the tagEvent function:

```
func tagEvent(eventName: String, attributes: [String : String]? = nil) {
    // Check for initialization
    if (!initialized) {
        openSession() { (success) in
            // perform your tagEvent code
        })
    } else {
        if let url = URL(string: self.baseUrl + "/event"),
            let sessionId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sessionId"){
            ...
            // make an API call to create an event with that sessionId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy is absolutely correct.  This is an asynchronous issue not a singleton issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to call openSession once in AppDelegate and call tagEvent where ever i want to use in application wide. In your case wouldn't it opens a session every time when I want to tag an event ?

Comment: Check the 3rd option I added.  You could streamline your code but hopefully this expresses the general idea.

Comment: But I have to call openSession or closeSession if needed also, i need one session for application wide, isn't it the same thing by keeping "initialized" application wide with by calling openSession and store the sessionId into UserDefaults?

Comment: My point in option #3, is you hide the synchronization logic inside of the class (in tagEvent) and it will wait for openSession to complete before executing the tagEvent code.  If it's already initialized, it will bypass this logic and go straight to executing the code for tagEvent.  The reason you are having issues is because you don't have synchronization built in your class (or outside of your class).  You have to solve this one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an "internal" class to provide a static reference to your Analytics class, as follows (note: remove `final` keyword):

```
class Analytics {

// properties ...

    class var sharedInstance: Analytics {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: Analytics = Analytics()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

// other methods (init(), openSession(), closeSession(), tagEvent())

}
```

Next call methods from your Analytics class in any other class, as follows:

```
Analytics.sharedInstance.openSession()
Analytics.sharedInstance.closeSession()
Analytics.sharedInstance.tagEvent( ... )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it results in a same way, tagEvent function runs  without waiting the openSession function which is making an async API call to create a session